# Read delimited file and split into groups by journal entry

Tags: c#, .net

I need to take an input file (CSV) containing journal entry line items and process them by journal entry.  A journal entry is defined by each distinct group by of Database and Date.

Sample CSV data:

> ```
> LineNo,Database,Date,Amount
> 1,DB3,03/12/2013,1.00
> 2,DB1,10/14/2013,1.00
> 3,DB2,08/12/2013,1.00
> 4,DB3,03/12/2013,1.00
> 5,DB2,08/12/2013,1.00
> 6,DB1,10/14/2013,1.00
> 7,DB1,08/12/2013,1.00
> 8,DB1,08/12/2013,1.00
> ```

An example of a group would be lines 7 and 8 above since they belong to a distinct database and have a distinct date. Same with lines 3 and 5.

What is the most effective/efficient code to loop through and examine each journal entry one at at time given that the lines in the CSV are not provided in any special order? I'll need to be able to reference each field and each record for a given journal entry.

I included my first successful attempt at reading the CSV below but am well aware that I am not reading it by each journal entry but rather am looking at it line by line, which is not terribly helpful.

I'd like to learn a better and more powerful technique for solving this problem if possible.

```
public static void SeparateJournalEntries()
{
   string UploadFilePath = @"\\server\folder\upload.csv";  
   var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(UploadFilePath));
   string previousSite = "";
   int JEcounter = -1;
   int lineNumber = 1;

   while (!reader.EndOfStream)
   {
      var line = reader.ReadLine();
      string[] fields = line.Split(',');
      Console.WriteLine(fields[0].ToString() + " " + fields[1].ToString());

      JEfields JEinstance = new JEfields
      {
         Database = fields[0],
         Date = fields[1],
         Amount = fields[2]
      };

      if (JEinstance.Site == previousSite || previousSite == System.String.Empty & lineNumber > 1)
      {
         JEcounter += 1;
         previousSite = JEinstance.Site;
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: 1) Your parsing code is just fine as-is.  You *MUST* read a .csv file line by line - there's nothing wrong with that :).  2) If you want to "aggregate" the data, perhaps you can use lists: One list for each different database, for example.  IMHO...

Comment: [Here](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is a good, free, and open-source component that is fantastic at parsing CSV files among other formats.

Comment: How large is this file? Can you fit it easily into memory? If it's not sorted, how far do you expect you need to backtrack to find a matching journal? If this is a small file, simply use a dictionary.

Comment: The file will be small at most 1000-2000 lines of data (often more like 500).  It will typically have about 100 databases that I will be writing to. It should fit easily into memory and I would typically not need to backtrack more than 5-10 lines to find a matching journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want is to group these values by a **unique key** defined using `{DbName,Date}`, and then create a mapping from each key into a list of entries.

Before anything else, you should create a class which represents this unique key, and make it implement the [`IEquatable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx). This will ensure that calling the `Equals` method on two different instances with equal database names and dates will return `true`, and is required for .NET mapping constructs to work propertly.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a unique journal info.
/// This class implements value-type comparison semantics.
/// </summary>
class JournalInfo : IEquatable<JournalInfo>
{
    private readonly string _dbName;
    /// <summary>Gets the database name.</summary>
    public string DbName
    { get { return _dbName; } }

    private readonly DateTime _date;
    /// <summary>Gets the date.</summary>
    public DateTime Date
    { get { return _date; } }

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="JournalInfo"/> class.</summary>
    public JournalInfo(string db, DateTime date)
    {
        _dbName = db; _date = date;
    }

    #region Equals overrides to ensure value-type comparison semantics

    // a lot of plumbing needs to be done here to solve a simple task,
    // but it must be done to ensure consistency in all cases

    /// <summary>Determines whether the specified <see cref="JournalInfo" /> is equal to this instance.</summary>
    public bool Equals(JournalInfo other)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) 
            return false;
        else 
            return this.DbName == other.DbName && this.Date == other.Date;
    }

    /// <summary>Determines whether the specified <see cref="System.Object" /> is equal to this instance.</summary>
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other as JournalInfo);
    }

    /// <summary>Returns a hash code for this instance, suitable for use in hashing algorithms and data structures like a hash table.</summary>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = 17;
        if (this.DbName != null) hash += this.DbName.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + this.Date.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(JournalInfo a, JournalInfo b)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
            return object.ReferenceEquals(b, null);

        return ((JournalInfo)a).Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(JournalInfo a, JournalInfo b)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
            return !object.ReferenceEquals(b, null);

        return !((JournalInfo)a).Equals(b);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now that you have this class ready, you can use it to create the `JournalEntry` class:

```
class JournalEntry
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public JournalInfo Info { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Having this in place, you can now use LINQ to group these values and map them to lists of entries:

```
var path = "input.txt";
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Dictionary<JournalInfo, List<JournalEntry>> map = 
    File.ReadLines(path) // lazy read one line at a time
        .Skip(1) // skip header
        .Select(line => line.Split(',')) // split into columns
        .Select((columns, lineNumber) => new JournalEntry() 
            {   // parse each line into a journal entry
                LineNumber = lineNumber,
                Info = new JournalInfo(
                    columns[1], 
                    DateTime.ParseExact(columns[2], "MM/dd/yyyy", culture)),

                Amount = decimal.Parse(columns[3], culture)
            })
        .GroupBy(entry => entry.Info) // group by unique key
        .ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key, grouping => grouping.ToList());
```

Now you can use a loop to dump this to console:

```
// this loop also orders entries by database name and date
foreach (var item in map.OrderBy(m => m.Key.DbName).ThenBy(m => m.Key.Date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Journal: {0} - {1:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
        item.Key.DbName, 
        item.Key.Date);

    foreach (var entry in item.Value.OrderBy(e => e.LineNumber))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" - Line {0}, Amount = {1:0.00}",
            entry.LineNumber,
            entry.Amount);
    }
}
```

For your input file, this code should print:

```
Journal: DB1 - 12.08.2013
 - Line 6, Amount = 1,00
 - Line 7, Amount = 1,00
Journal: DB1 - 14.10.2013
 - Line 1, Amount = 1,00
 - Line 5, Amount = 1,00
Journal: DB2 - 12.08.2013
 - Line 2, Amount = 1,00
 - Line 4, Amount = 1,00
Journal: DB3 - 12.03.2013
 - Line 0, Amount = 1,00
 - Line 3, Amount = 1,00
```

Answer (score 3):

As you're asking for the most efficient way I'm not 100% certain of the actual answer, but this is what I would do:

```
List<string[]> listofArraysofStrings = new List<string[]>();

foreach (string line in file.Lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
    listofArraysofStrings.Items.Add(parts);
}
```

Then you can run something like

```
if (listofArraysofStrings[0][1] == "DB1")
{
     // Do something
}
```

You could also use the string.Split() method to split the date, then you can get a day month year. Potentially even converting it into an array of custom classes, then use a constructor to initialise it with all elements at once.

Using a class would help you in keeping your code clean. My best advice would be to initialise an array of classes, then to evaluate the classes and delete whatever you don't need from the list. I can't see any better way than that personally.

Here is a sample class:

```
class JournalEntry
{
    int _dd, _mm, _yy, _linenumber;
    string _database;
    float _amount;

    public JournalEntry(int dd, int mm, int yy, int linenumber, string database, float amount)
    {
        _linenumber = linenumber;
        _database = database;
        _dd = dd;
        _mm = mm;
        _yy = yy;
        _amount = amount;
    }
}
```

And a sample implementation:

```
List<JournalEntry> journalEntryList = new List<JournalEntry>();
JournalEntry je;
foreach (string line in file.Lines)
{
    string[] mls = line.Split(','); // mls is short for MyLineSplit
    string[] dateinfo = mls[2].Split('/');
    je = new JournalEntry(mls[0], mls[1], Convert.ToInt32(dateinfo[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dateinfo[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateinfo[2]), mls[3]);
    journalEntryList.Items.Add(je);
}
```

Hope this all makes sense, note that I haven't compiled it or anything. Also note that there is no exception handling on the Convert.ToInt32(), you may wish to use Int32.TryParse(), but I can't remember the exact layout of that code at the minute and don't have a C# IDE to hand.

A small addition is that the benefits of this method include that the list can be added to and removed from far more easily than an array, although at the expense of some efficiency, but also that you no longer need to increment any global counter, as you can call list.Items.Count to find out how many values you have!

Another note to anyone who may stumble upon this: Using a dictionary would be advantageous as it will provide easier methods to sort and arrange your data, as well as increasing performance and accessibility.

Comment: If you are suggesting to load the entire file into memory, then you should at least use a dictionary to group these items as OP explained.

Comment: @Groo - True that, as mentioned already I didn't have an IDE to hand, so just scraped this together from memory, the result being I could only provide code I know. Thanks for the input though, I'll add it to the post as a suggestion in case anyone should discover this later on.

Answer (score 1):

I would employ the power of Linq and objects to solve this problem. You can use a single Linq statement to read in and sort the file. You can then loop through the Journal object in your desired order, or easily reorder them.

To read in and sort file:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<Journal> sortedJournals = GetJournals(@"c:\temp\test.txt");

        //now you can loop through sortedJournals

        //or you can create groups of journals
        var journalByDatabase = sortedJournals.ToLookup(j => j.Database + j.Date);

        foreach (var group in journalByDatabase)
        {
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Journal> GetJournals(string JournalsPath)
    {

        var myJournals =
            from c in
                (
                    from line in File.ReadAllLines(JournalsPath).Skip(1)
                    let aRecord = line.Split(',')
                    select new Journal()
                    {
                        LineNo = Convert.ToInt32(aRecord[0].Trim()),
                        Database = aRecord[1].Trim(),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(aRecord[2].Trim()),
                        Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(aRecord[3].Trim()),
                    }
                ).OrderBy(x => x.Database)
            select c;

        return myJournals;

    }
```

The simple journal class:

```
public class Journal
{
    public int LineNo { get ;set;}
    public string Database { get; set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public Journal()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Using concatenated strings as hash keys often leads to collisions, if not thoughtfully constructed. Are you sure that `j.Database + j.Date` generates unique keys?

Comment: He did not require unique keys. The idea was to group journal entries where Database & Date matched. Concatenating these two fields accomplishes that.

Comment: Consider entries `("DB1","12/3/2013")` and `("DB11","2/3/2013")`. Your code will generate the same key for both of them: `"DB112/3/2013"` and put them in the same group. I am not sure what you meant by "he did not require unique keys", but I am pretty sure these two entries don't belong to the same group. In this example, you can easily fix it, but that's an example of why one needs to be careful when using strings as keys. They are temptingly simple, but apart for giving (slightly) worse performance than a proper tuple implementation, they often result in subtle collision errors.

Comment: Thanks Groo you are absolutely right, your way is the better solution, and it would be a little hackish but you could delimit the "key" with pipe symbol |